# how to get number of compressed bytes written, while using gz lib, in c/c++?

Tags: zlib, compression

I have a question on `zlib`. How can I know the number of compressed bytes written? I am using `gzwrite(...)`. As we know it returns the number of uncompressed (actual) bytes written.

Should I use some other API instead of `gzwrite()`?

What I am doing,
- I have a .gz output file. I keep writing to the file when I have some content available. I also want to track the file so that it does not cross a certain size. I do not want to use `stat() linux API` as my writing is very frequent.

Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to write debug logs to files of size max 10 MB (compressed). I get the logs from an internal module. So when I get logs it can be 1Kb or as big as 30KB, no fixed size. I need to keep adding the logs to the output file compressed way. I am using gzwrite for this matter. And when the output file reaches 10MB I create another file with a new name. So to check the size 10MB, I need to track the size. As said the log incoming is very frequent so I do not want to use any system call such as stat().

Answer (score 5):

zlib provides the `gzoffset()` function for this purpose.  It returns the current offset in the file being read or written.

Comment: I will try this. Any sample or example would really help.

Comment: `number_of_compressed_bytes_written = gzoffset(gzip_file_handle);`

Comment: Hi, It worked. Thanks! Initially it was giving 0 but after doing gzflush(file, Z_FINISH) it gave proper value. Is it an overhead to call gzoffset() often? Because in my SW this will always be on in the device.

Comment: No, there should be very little overhead.

Comment: Thanks. If I open a gzFile in append mode and do gzoffset() I get 0 bytes. But when I write something and do gzflush() and then call gzoffset(), it gives me proper values. Is this expected? gzoffset() uses any system API such as stat() internally?

Comment: calling gzflush() with Z_FINISH has any overhead? Because without the gzflush() I see gzoffset() gives 0 always.

Comment: Before writing to the file, I tried to do gzoffset() and I compared the size with stat(). I see gzoffset() always gives 20 bytes more. What I do? -- I open the file in append(ab9) mode. First flush with gzflush(). Then I do gzoffset() to check current size. Then I do gzwrite() to write the content. Then I do gzflush() and gzoffset(). After writing the size in stat() API and gzoffset() are same. Is this expected?

Comment: Calling `gzflush()` forces the compression of the data provided so far and writing that data to the output.  If used too often, it will degrade compression significantly, as well as increase the time required to compress.  It should not be used just to get progress information.  Compression needs to accumulate data to gather history and statistics, and will write out data periodically in chunks.  You simply need to be patient, and you will see the value returned by `gzoffset()` increase after each chunk that is written.

Comment: If you are only writing a small amount of data, then you will never see the value returned by `gzoffset()` increase since nothing will be written until you do a `gzclose()`.  Unless a `gzflush()` is used before that.

Comment: The fact that zero is returned initially when appending is a quirk of `open()` with `O_APPEND`.  The offset returned by `lseek()` is not updated to after the original file contents until the first `write()`.

Comment: If you want to avoid writing a file larger than some large size, then you need to watch the output of `gzoffset()` (without using `gzflush()`) and stop when it gets to the limit minus twice the typical amount chunked out when compressing.

Comment: `stat()` will return what has actually been written to the file, whereas `gzoffset()` (or `lseek()`) will return what has been buffered by the operating system to write to the file.  The result of `stat()` will often be less.

Comment: Thanks Much!
So how can I find the size of the file initially (before writing anything)? I tried by opening it in a read mode but failed.

gzoffset() after gzclose() will not work, right? So do I need to open the file again (may be in read mode)?

Comment: On this:
stat() will return what has actually been written to the file, whereas gzoffset() (or lseek()) will return what has been buffered by the operating system to write to the file. The result of stat() will often be less.

Then how can I manage with gzoffset()? Finally the size can be lesser in actual. As I said stat() we dont want to use.

Comment: `gzoffset()` is more accurate than `stat()`, since what `gzoffset()` is reporting definitely _will_ be written to the file.